# command to create new X11 session

Tags: x11

I can create a new X11 session, by clicking new session. However this locks the current session.

I am currently doing a lot of testing with X11, and need to quickly create a new session, without locking the current one. How do I do this?

---

System: Debian Gnu/Linux with X11.

I knew how to do this once. May have even read it on here. But whenever I search, I find stuff on `su` and `sudo`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're on a Unix variant such as Linux that supports multiple virtual consoles, switch to a different console, log in in text mode, and run `startx :1`. The [`startx`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.9.0/doc/html/startx.1.html) command starts a new X session. The argument `:1` means to use this value for the display number. Each X11 server running on the same machine needs to have a different display number, and the first one that you're already in is `:0`.

To switch to a different console on Linux and *BSD, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. Depending on how your system is set up (which depends on your distribution and your display manager and how they're configured), the default X11 console may be 1, 2, 5, 7 or some other number.

Note that `startx` runs different initialization files from a GUI login. Depending on how your dot files are set up and on what you're testing, this may or may not test what you want. A GUI login traditionally runs `.Xsession`, but usually these days the display manager (that's the program where you type your username and password in graphic mode) lets you choose a session type and runs whatever initialization files this session type uses. `startx` runs `~/.xinitrc`.

If your desktop environment has a “new session” menu option and this locks the display, it probably has a configuration setting where you can choose not to lock the display, but this is entirely dependent on the desktop environment.

Comment: Because this runs different initialisation program, it is not useful for me. I remember some command, that I could type. It did exactly the same as clicking new session, but there was an option to not lock the current session.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You should ask a new question where you state which desktop environment you're using (and what version on what distribution, and how you've configured it) and ask how to not lock the current session.